# Flying with a bicycle with Swiss/Austrian/Brussels airlines

Tags: air-travel, airports, bookings, bicycles, swiss

I'll fly from Vienna to Porto, round trip, and on the way back I want to bring a bicycle with me.

I've two options for the same price and same schedule but with different airlines.

Option 1, all segments with Brussels Airlines:

> Vienna - Brussels - Porto - Brussels - Vienna

Option 2, from and to Vienna with Autrian and from and to Porto with Swiss

> Vienna - Geneve - Porto - Zurich - Vienna

As I only want to bring my bicycle in one journey of the trip (Porto to Vienna), I've a few doubts.

Brussels airlines [says](https://www.brusselsairlines.com/en-at/practical-information/travel-info/before-the-flight/luggage-info/music-and-sports/default.aspx):

> If your sports equipment doesn't fit in the overhead compartment or
>   the seat in front of you, it has to be transported in the hold (width
>   + height + depth max 158 cm).

For Brussels airlines, size and weight does matter and my bicycle size is over their limit.

Swiss airlines [says](https://www.swiss.com/at/EN/prepare/baggage/special-baggage):

> We are happy to transport your sports equipment subject to no extra
>   charge, provided that you do not exceed your baggage allowance.

Austrian airlines [says](https://www.austrian.com/Info/Flying/Baggage.aspx?sc_lang=en&cc=US):

> Sports baggage is carried without a surcharge as long as the baggage
>   allowance shown on your ticket is not exceeded either in terms of the
>   number of items or weight.

For Swiss and Austrian airlines size is not a problem.

They all mention a fee of 50€ for bringing a bicycle but they also mention not having to pay the fee as long as I do not exceed my baggage allowance.

My questions are:

1- If I book an economy ticket with check in baggage (but not bringing any but just the bicycle) will I have to pay the 50€ fee extra for bringing the bicycle with me or that is included and part of my baggage allowance?

2- If I've to pay the 50€ fee is it per flight (making it a total of 100€ to bring my bicycle, 50€ Porto - Zurich and 50€ more for the flight Zurich - Vienna) or is it per trip (50€ for the whole return trip Porto - Vienna, making it a total of 50€)?

Answer (score 1):

I called Swiss Airlines, which is the ticket issuer, and they told me:

1- we have to pay the 50€ fee regardless we have checked in luggage allowance or not.

2- We pay the 50€ per leg and not per flight. So in my case I'll pay 50€ to bring my bicycle from Porto to Vienna, with a stoppage in Zurich.